# How to annotate or tag the commit with release type in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is the any way to annotate or tag changes/commits in gitlab for different release types?
Can there be a change to gitlab workflow , where the committer is required to tag the commit with release type?

How to annotate or tag the commit with release type in gitlab?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the release type in Gitlab? And what prevents you to tag a commit in Gitlab CI/CD? This should be straight forward. Please add the YAML you have so far to your question and link to the feature in the docs you're asking about so it becomes more clear what **specifically** you're asking about.

Comment: I need to restrict user to be committed if he is not committing with release type

Comment: Add all the important details to the question. _(IIRC you can't restrict the user to commit based on that. You can only make a build fail)_